# Crystal report data record selection and printing with condition

Tags: ms-access, crystal-reports

I have 103 records in data and I want to print data from 1st, 27th, 53, 79 records in first page; in second page, records 2nd, 28th, 54, 80;
in third page, records 3, 29, 55, 81; sequence up to last page.

Comment: Is the requirement dynamic or static?

Comment: my requirement is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put a sequencial field in your record. Let's call it "Result.Sequential".
2. Create a formula. Let's call it "group".

   {Result.Sequential} mod 26 //the result is the page number of the record
3. Create a group by the formula.
4. In section expert, put a formula in "new page before".

   groupnumber > 1 //to avoid a blank page in the beginning

Notes:

You can use a parameter of the report instead of fixing the number 26.

If you cannot include a sequential in your records, you will have to find a creative way to do something similar. Putting the "recordnumber" in the formula will not work.